# Launch Fancybox on page load without clicking only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want to launch a **Fancybox 2** element when the page loads, but to only load once. I want to add a session cookie for at least **50** days.

So far I've got the Fancybox element loading when the page loads:

```
window.jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox.open('#popup_box');
});
```

But I can't figure out how to implement it within a cookie if/else statement:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // set cookie
    $.cookie('firstvisit', 1, {expires: 50});

    if ($.cookie('firstvisit') === 1) {
        //Do stuff if cookie doesn't exist like set a cookie with a value of 1
        $('#popup_box').hide();
    } else {
        $('#popup_box').show();
    }

});
```

I don't want the **Fancybox 2** element to display if the user has visited the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check for cookie is set or not in browser. if not then set cookie and open pop up.
if yes then pop up will not open.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // set cookie
   if(!$.cookie('firstvisit')){
     $.cookie('firstvisit', 1, {expires: 50});
     $.fancybox.open('#popup_box');
   }    
});
```

Comment: @jvanstan happy to help you :)